# Reduzir código PHP

Tags: php

Como eu poderia usar um laço de repetição para reduzir a quantidade de linhas desse código ou se há alguma outra maneira de reduzir tudo isso?

```html
<div class="form-group ">
    <input type="file" class="form-control mr-3 my-3" name="imagem2" id="input_imagem_2" required/>
    <small id="menuHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Primeira Imagem.</small>
</div>
```

```php
if(isset($_FILES['imagem1']) && $_FILES['imagem1']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem1']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem1']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome1 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome1;  

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['imagem2']) && $_FILES['imagem2']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem2']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem2']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome2 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome2;  

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['imagem3']) && $_FILES['imagem3']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem3']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem3']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome3 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome3;  

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['imagem4']) && $_FILES['imagem4']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem4']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem4']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome4 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome4;  

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['imagem5']) && $_FILES['imagem5']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem5']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem5']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome5 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome5;  

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['imagem6']) && $_FILES['imagem6']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem6']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem6']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome6 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome6; 

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}


if(isset($_FILES['imagem7']) && $_FILES['imagem7']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem7']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem7']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome7 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome7; 

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['imagem8']) && $_FILES['imagem8']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem8']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem8']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome8 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome8; 

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['imagem9']) && $_FILES['imagem9']['error'] == 0)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem9']['tmp_name'];
    $nome1 = $_FILES['imagem9']['name'];


    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome1, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
    {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        $imagemNome9 = md5(microtime()) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $imagemNome9; 

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
        {  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia descrever em palavras quais são as entradas do código, o que ele faz e qual é a saída gerada?

Comment: bom e para salvar files, no caso imagens no caso esse seria o codigo html ```                                                <div class="form-group ">
                                                    <input type="file" class="form-control mr-3 my-3" name="imagem2" id="input_imagem_2" required/>
                                                    <small id="menuHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Primeira Imagem.</small>
                                                </div>```

Comment: o que muda e o name="imagem2", name="imagem3" e assim vai.., porem o codigo em php para verificacao dos arquivos acaba sendo muito grande

Answer (score 1):

O `$_FILES` é um [array associativo](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php), então você pode fazer uso do `foreach` e percorrer todos os itens enviados.

> Exemplo:

```
<?php

// criando vetor com as extensões permitidas
$extensoesPermitidas = ['.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.png'];

// percorro todas as chaves no vetor.
foreach($_FILES as $arquivo) {
    if($arquivo['error'] == 0)
    {
        // recupera a extensão e coloca a mesma em caixa baixa
        $extensao = strtolower(strrchr($nome1, '.'));

        // verificando quais a extensões permitidas
        if(in_array($extensao, $extensoesPermitidas))
        {
            // criando nome para imagem
            $nomeImagem = md5(microtime() . '_' . uniqid()) . '.' . $extensao;

            // Concatena a pasta com o nome
            $destino = '../img_usuario_tema_1/' . $nomeImagem;  

            // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
            move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'], $destino)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anderson, editei com fontes. Mas para melhor entendimento de sua parte $_FILES é sim um array associativo, o foreach traz por padrão o valor e não a chave do array. Só que o valor do array associativo é um outro array associativo e dentro destes sim existe a chave `tmp_name`.

Comment: Nossa, esquece, mal meu. Eu confundi quando envia mais de um arquivo com o mesmo nome. Desculpa.